# How do I center all of my puts statements in a program without applying the center method to each string?

Tags: ruby

So I have this code:

```
puts "hey".center(150)
puts "yo".center(150)
puts "sup".center(150)
```

How do I make this shorter and more concise? I was thinking of editing the original puts method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define a method like this:

```
def my_puts(str)
  puts str.center(150)
end
```

And use it like:

```
my_puts "hey"
my_puts("yo")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator.

```
["hey", "yo", "sup"].each { |word| puts word.center(150) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
puts %w{hey yo sup}.map { |str| str.center(150) }
```